# attribute is missing the android specific namespace

Tags: android, eclipse

Here is the snippet of main.xml.Although android:layout_width is used its giving attribute is missing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TextView android:id="@+id/eventlabel" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="10px" 
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:paddingBottom="10px"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Could someone point out the mistake?Thanks

Comment: Is that the entire layout XML?

Comment: clean your project and refresh your eclipse

Comment: yes..its entire xml file ..i did refresh and clean but to no avail

Comment: try to remove "android:layout_width" line and recreate it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools
```

Change it to:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    <!-- rest is the same -->
```

You only had `xmlns=...` and didn't actually specify the `android` part of it. Also, your `tools` XMLNS was missing a closing `"`

Comment: @vindhya You completely ignore my first point. Change `xmlns="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` to `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning your solution and then build it again.